# C++ free() changing other memory

Tags: c++

I started noticing that sometimes when deallocating memory in some of my programs, they would inexplicably crash. I began narrowing down the culprit and have come up with an example that illustrates a case that I am having difficulty understanding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
char *tmp = (char*)malloc(16);
char *tmp2 = (char*)malloc(16);

long address = reinterpret_cast<long>(tmp);
long address2 = reinterpret_cast<long>(tmp2);
cout << "tmp = " << address << "\n";
cout << "tmp2 = " << address2 << "\n";

memset(tmp, 1, 16);
memset(tmp2, 1, 16);

char startBytes[4] = {0};
char endBytes[4] = {0};

memcpy(startBytes, tmp - 4, 4);
memcpy(endBytes, tmp + 16, 4);
cout << "Start: " << static_cast<int>(startBytes[0]) << " " << static_cast<int>(startBytes[1]) << " " << static_cast<int>(startBytes[2]) << " " << static_cast<int>(startBytes[3]) << "\n";
cout << "End: " << static_cast<int>(endBytes[0]) << " " << static_cast<int>(endBytes[1]) << " " << static_cast<int>(endBytes[2]) << " " << static_cast<int>(endBytes[3]) << "\n";
cout << "---------------\n";

free(tmp);

memcpy(startBytes, tmp - 4, 4);
memcpy(endBytes, tmp + 16, 4);
cout << "Start: " << static_cast<int>(startBytes[0]) << " " << static_cast<int>(startBytes[1]) << " " << static_cast<int>(startBytes[2]) << " " << static_cast<int>(startBytes[3]) << "\n";
cout << "End: " << static_cast<int>(endBytes[0]) << " " << static_cast<int>(endBytes[1]) << " " << static_cast<int>(endBytes[2]) << " " << static_cast<int>(endBytes[3]) << "\n";

free(tmp2);

return 0;
}
```

Here is the output that I am seeing:

```
tmp = 8795380
tmp2 = 8795400
Start: 16 0 0 0
End: 16 0 0 0
---------------
Start: 17 0 0 0
End: 18 0 0 0
```

I am using Borland's free compiler. I am aware that the header bytes that I am looking at are implementation specific, and that things like "reinterpret_cast" are bad practice. The question I am merely looking to find an answer to is: why does the first byte of "End" change from 16 to 18?

The 4 bytes that are considered "end" are 16 bytes after tmp, which are 4 bytes before tmp2. They are tmp2's header - why does a call to free() on tmp affect this place in memory?

I have tried the same example using new [] and delete [] to create/delete tmp and tmp2 and the same results occur.

Any information or help in understanding why this particular place in memory is being affected would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not related, but c++ programmers should use new and delete (or new[] and delete[]), not malloc and free.

Comment: Even more general, if you are using `new[]` and `delete[]`, you might really want `std::vector`.

Comment: I can't +1 J.N.'s comment again, but I would if I could!

Comment: I stumbled upon this originally using new and delete. I tested afterwards with malloc and free and simply kept it for the example to post here. The results of using either are identical - the byte is inexplicably changed once tmp is deallocated.

Comment: If you can't use `new` and `delete` (in some form) then you're losing a significant portion of the power of C++.

Comment: If you're trying to understand how memory allocation is implemented by your compiler & run-time, you should look at the source code. I haven't used Borland C++ in many years, but I believe it came with the source code to the run-time so that you could step through it in the debugger if necessary.

Comment: Did you mean to `memcpy` with `tmp` after freeing it or is that a typo?

Comment: @Jason Terranova - Well the reason libc manipulates memory does not matter, but the fact of it does. This fact, as you have found, makes resolving heap corruption harder. You have to be aware that the heap is being changed by code other than your own explicit code. Good on you for peeking into this for a learning exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to ask your `libc` implementation why it changes.  In any case, why does it matter?  This is a memory area that libc has not allocated to you, and may be using to maintain its own data structures or consistency checks, or may not be using at all.

Comment: It was merely a question out of curiosity, but regardless you are correct - the reason does not matter since it is not memory that I use.

Comment: @Jason Terranova, that wasn't sarcasm, any reason is going to be implementation-dependent.  If, e.g., you're on Linux using glibc, check out the source for your glibc release and dig in.  If you don't know your libc implementation, then your question can't be answered, in general:  "X is undefined behavior.  Why do I see Y when I do X anyway?"

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are looking at memory you didn't allocate. You can't make any supposition on what happens to the memory outside what you requested (ie the 16 bytes you allocated). There is nothing abnormal going on.

The runtime and compilers are free to do whatever they want to do with them so you should not use them in your programs. The runtime probably change the values of those bytes to keep track of its internal state.
Deallocating memory is very unlikely to crash a program. On the other hand, accessing memory you have deallocated like in your sample is big programming mistake that is likely to do so.

A good way to avoid this is to set any pointers you free to NULL. Doing so you'll force your program to crash when accessing freed variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the act of removing an allocated element from the heap modifies other heap nodes, or that the implementation reserves one or more bytes of headers for use as guard bytes from previous allocations.

Answer (score 0):

The memory manager must remember for example what is the size of the memory block that has been allocated with `malloc`. There are different ways, but probably the simplest one is to just allocate 4 bytes more than the size requested in the call and store the size value just before the pointer returned to the caller.

The implementation of `free` can then subtract 4 bytes from the passed pointer to get a pointer to where the size has been stored and then can link the block (for example) to a list of free reusable blocks of that size (may be using again those 4 bytes to store the link to next block).

You are not supposed to change or even look at bytes before/after the area you have allocated. The result of accessing, even just for reading, memory that you didn't allocate is Undefined Behavior (and yes, you really can get a program to really crash or behave crazily just because of reading memory that wasn't allocated).